# PHP split and spaces

Tags: php, regex

When I split a string with spaces it's not removing the sapces.  My string looks like this:

```
$string = 'one - two - three';
```

My PHP call looks like this:

```
list($blk1, $blk2, $blk3) = split('\s*\-\s*', $string);
```

I would assume the regex will split on zero or more spaces but the spaces remain in the resulting array.

Any idea why?

Comment: don't use split :( --> use preg_split

Answer (score 3):

[`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is long ago deprecated in PHP. Consider using [`preg_split'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$string = 'one - two - three';
list($blk1, $blk2, $blk3) = preg_split('/\s*\-\s*/', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure what to tell you on the direct question but as you can see on the man page http://php.net/split this function is deprecated, you shouldn't rely on it.

Why don't you just use explode like this:

```
$string = 'one - two - three';
$parts = explode(' - ', $string);
$blk1 = $parts[0];
$blk2 = $parts[1];
$blk3 = $parts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using explode() ?

```
function trim_value(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}

$array = explode("-", $string);

array_walk($array, 'trim_value');
```

There you go: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ULr1NO

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
[\s-]+
```

Not 100% familiar with php but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a counter against regular expressions for such trivial task with a delimited string:

```
$string = 'one - two - three';
$parts = explode(' - ', $string);
array_walk($parts, 'trim');
var_dump($parts);
```